# Que signifie « On s’est décrit nos croissances respectives » ?

Tags: sens, expressions

Que signifie l'expression « On s’est décrit nos croissances respectives » dans ce passage :

> j’ai couché avec la fille des voisins. Elle, elle ne se prenait pas pour n’importe qui. ***On s’est décrit nos croissances respectives***. Cadavérique, je vomissais tout ce qui pouvait garnir ma tirelire. Je donnais sans qu’on ne me le demande. Je donnais et perdais continuellement en échange.

Comment: Tu n'aurais pas un peu plus de contexte pour cette phrase ?

Comment: j'ai ajouté plus de contexte mais peut être ça change rien à la compréhension de la phrase.

Comment: Ça vient de quel genre de texte ? A première vue ça a l'air sans queue ni tête. Soit c'est de la traduction automatique qui n'a vraiment pas marché, soit c'est un genre littéraire qui ne me fait pas envie...

Comment: De quel livre est-ce extrait ? Un roman ? Les personnages sont-ils des personnes en pleine ascension sociale  (j'ai alors une interprétation) ?

Comment: D'accord avec @Jean-ClaudeArbaut, pour moi la signification est du genre "on a comparé qui a la plus grosse expérience sexuelle", mais honnêtement j'ai jamais vu ça ailleurs ...

Comment: ça vient pas d'un livre mais d'un libre réflexion d'une personne qui ne s'identifie pas en tant qu'écrivain.

Comment: Je vous remercie tous

Answer (score 0):

Cela manque de contexte pour pouvoir définir clairement un sens: le texte est-il issu d'une traduction ? Quel est le niveau de français de l'auteur ? Cherche-t-il à faire de la poésie, ou employer un style imagé ?

En prenant la phrase dans son sens littéral, on peut interpréter qu'il se décrivent la manière dont ils ont physiquement grandi (leur croissance dans le sens "développement du corps"). "Respectives" veut dire qu'ils ont chacun décrit leur propre croissance à l'autre.

Auquel cas l'auteur décrit manifestement par la suite un trouble de l'alimentation (type anorexie). Il parle d'être cadavérique (apparence d'un cadavre, émacié, famélique), de vomir tout le temps, ne pas réussir à prendre de poids.

> garnir ma tirelire

Dans le sens grossir, s'engraisser, gagner du poids. Le corps étant comparé à une tirelire que l'on rempli.

> Je donnais

= vomir, régurgiter.